# How to use a command-line tool to extract a bibtex reference that contains a search term?

Tags: bibtex, tools

I'd like to be able to use a tool like `grep` to extract an entire bibtex reference rather than just the matching line.
For example, `grep Smith mydatabase.bib` would return lines that contain the word `Smith`. I'd like to have a command-line program that returned the entire bibtex reference that encloses the word `Smith`.

- How can this be done on the command-line?

In particular, I'd be interested in whether there is a way of using `sed` or `awk` to perform the task?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`bibtool --select {"Smith"} <file>.aux -o <file>.bib` creates a new bibliography data file which has only entries with Smith.

`bibtool` should be part of your TeX distribution.

Comment: Thanks. For those interested `bibtool '--select{"Smith"}' mydatabase.bib` did what I wanted (i.e., send matches to standard out). It took me a little while to realise that on my shell I needed to enclose the `--select{...}` in single quotes.

Comment: what kind of shell do you have?

Comment: bash on Ubuntu...

Comment: The bad thing with bibtool is the single quotes. If you want to automate things you can't pass variables (e.g. `$a`).

Answer (score 10):

The `bib2bib` command line tool provides pretty flexible and reliable ways to filter/extract bibtex entries according to certain criteria. This (little known) utility is part of the [bibtex2html](http://www.lri.fr/~filliatr/bibtex2html/) tool suite. (Note: you have to look for the **PDF** documentation, the HTML documentation does not discuss `bib2bib`!)

For instance, to extract all entries where `Smith` is an author, one just writes:

```
bib2bib -oc smith-citations -ob smith.bib -c 'author : "Smith"' mydatabase.bib
```

Multiple conditions can be grouped and combined with and/or/not, so you could extend the above query to include also references that mention `Smith` in the title, abstract, or whatever.

A big plus of `bib2bib` compared to "hand-crafted" `awk/sed/grep` solutions is that it deals very well with string constants, crossrefs and so on (you can either include all dependencies in the output file or let `bib2bib` expand them, so that the entries are self-contained).

Answer (score 4):

This kind of thing is a complete nuisance to do properly with the standard textutils, because Bibtex is not properly specified and the tools are not good at processing files if they are not structured by line.

You can get something close to what you want using `tr` to convert bib items into lines and back again.  E.g.:

```
<input.bib tr "@\n" "\n\0"|grep -a article|(tr "\n\0" "@\n")
```

will select all bib items with the word article in them.

Two issues:

1. The way this handles `@` is crufty: occurrences within entries will cause them to be split into two lines and the first `@` will be dropped.  This can be fixed, but it will make the scripts more complex.
2. The lines between tr-conversions contain lots of \0 characters, which means that many textutils will either not handle them or will need to have switches passed to them: here `grep` needs the `-a` switch.

### Postscript

The following function definitions perform a slightly more sophisticated conversion that handles `@` better (and uses `sed`):

```
bib2unix () { if test "$# > 0"; then cat "$@"; else cat; fi | tr "@\n" "\n\0" | sed "2,\$s/^/@/"; }
unix2bib () { tr -d "\n" | tr "\0" "\n"; }
```

which can be used so:

```
bib2unix input.bib |grep -a @article| unix2bib
```

to select all articles and cat them to STDOUT.

Answer (score 2):

If you do not need to process it further in an automated way (i.e., if you do not care about extra garbage), a quick and dirty solution is `grep -10 Smith mydatabase.bib` (the number is adjustable). This option (which appears to be a GNU extension) makes grep output not only the matching line, but also 10 lines of additional context on either side, which should be more than enough to contain the whole bibtex entry.

Comment: Could you please explain in more details what such a `grep` does?

Comment: It searches the file for all lines containing "Smith", and outputs each together with 10 lines of leading and trailing context (the idea being that the bibtex entry fits within this context). This option seems to be a GNU extension.

Comment: Cheers! I should've mentioned that it would more sense to add the details on the option to your answer (by editing it) instead of as a comment.

Answer (score 2):

Although I prefer the dedicated tools such as `bibtool` and `bib2bib`, here is one way of doing the task with awk.

- `awk 'BEGIN {RS="\n@"} /Smith/{print "@" $0}' mydatabase.bib`

  - The record separator `\n@` works if the bibtex database is formatted
      neatly with `@` always appearing in the first column.
  - `{print "@' $0}` is optional. It replaces the `@` removed by making
      `@` part of the record separator. This would be important if the
      bibtex records are being piped to another location.
- `awk -v RS='\n@' '/Smith/' mydatabase.bib`

  - This an abbreviated version of similar to above
  - `-v RS='\n@'` sets the record separator variable on the command-line.

Answer (score 2):

If you used the program [papis](http://github.com/alejandrogallo/papis) it would be something like this

```
papis list --format '{doc[ref]}'
```

and a demonstration in my highly imperfect library is here:

https://asciinema.org/a/Ewf73H6aZqJIrp6bz0kgWFbyJ