# Is there a way to get all references from a .bib file?

Tags: bibtex, pdf

I have a "large" .bib file. I want to have the list of references as a single pdf file. Is it possible to get a list with out running it along with a .tex file?

Question is as mentioned in the title:

Is there a way to get all references as a pdf file from a .bib file?

Comment: What about a minimal document using \nocite{*}?

Comment: Also this may help: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23878/how-to-quickly-convert-a-single-bibtex-reference-into-a-formatted-reference

Comment: @Ivan I mentioned the response as a comment in below answer

Answer (score 3):

AFAIK, there is no way to do this without a `.tex` file, especially since without any specification there, the `.bib` would not know which style it should set the bibliography in.
Is there any reason, you could not use a minimalistic document like this?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[%
style=authoryear-comp, % or whatever style you want
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{thatLargeBib.bib}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography[heading=none] % if you still want a title, delete that option
\end{document}
```

Comment: It says "Paragraph ended before \@fileswith@ptions was complete.
Undefined control sequence. \printbibliography"

Comment: It compiles normally for me using [this sample.bib](http://tug.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/aguplus/sample.bib).
Maybe check your `.bib` file for misplaced commas or brackets

Comment: The same file  compiled correctly when I used with some .tex file. I am not sure what could be an issue

Comment: Is there a website that helps me to check this misplaced commas and brackets? I really do not understand what could be an issue if it is working for the other file..

Comment: I just thought of another possible cause: do you use any commands inside any field of you ``.bib``? That would explain, why another ``.tex`` file can handle the bib, assuming the command is defined there. Try looking for ``\`` in your ``.bib`` and check all occurrences.

Comment: Yes, I see there are many \ There are used to support the font. for example, I have written \'etale

Answer (score 0):

if the .bib file size less than 25MB, you can try [bibtex-converter](https://asouqi.github.io/bibtex-converter), which I wrote, to convert the list of references BibTeX to a pdf.

Comment: When linking to your own site or content (or content that you are affiliated with), you [must disclose your affiliation _in the answer_](/help/promotion) in order for it not to be considered spam. Having the same text in your username as the URL or mentioning it in your profile is not considered sufficient disclosure under Stack Exchange policy.