# How do I install bibtex on a Mac?

Tags: bibtex, mac

I want to convert a `bibtex` citation into a human readable citation to paste into my editor. That is all.

A [solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23878/how-to-quickly-convert-a-single-bibtex-reference-into-a-formatted-reference) that I found makes use of `bibtex2html`, which is fine.

However, this needs `bibtex` to be installed. (Not BibDesk, not `biber`, nor MacTeX, nor `biblatex`) and I don't seem to be able to able to find this in `homebrew`, and it is not discussed on this page (https://www.bibtex.org/Links/).

How do I install `bibtex` on a Mac?

Comment: Do you have Texlive/Mactex installed? If so... Otherwise, the best way to do it is to use something like Zotero and find the link to the citation. If there aren't many of those, it's quite fast.

Comment: @user574859 Yeah I've got mactex installed (took a while to download) but bibtex is not on my path :/. Yeah, I guess I should add that, I'm doing this to quickly turn  (arxiv) links into citations - so I want to do this from the command line. I looked into zotero but it doesn't seem to be easily scriptable.

Comment: Yes, Zotero works in this case for a couple of citations. It seems you've got a whole database, though. A workaround would be to use Overleaf and copy-paste the whole thing.

Comment: [pandoc](https://pandoc.org) can do this trick (and a gazillion more)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.se. If you have installed MacTeX you should definitely have `bibtex` (and `biber`) and all of the other standard binaries in TeX Live installed.   And it should have set up the paths properly. Did you restart the Terminal after installing?

Comment: I did not... but creating a new terminal seems to have fixed this. Interesting. 

I'm used to being able to immediately use a terminal program in the same shell, so I've document this in my own answer to the quesiton rather than deleting.

Comment: Since the TeX binaries are installed in `/Library/TeX/texbin` that path is part of your path until you login again.

Comment: @AlanMunn 'not'.

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question.

You can install `mactex` with `brew install mactex`. But bibtex will only be on your path after you start a new terminal. I needed to create a completely new terminal tab / window (not just a new shell within a terminal).

`bibtex` was located here: `/Library/TeX/texbin/bibtex`.

Comment: No real need to use Homebrew to install MacTeX though.

Comment: Sure. Though as a programmer I install everything with homebrew.